# How to execute a scp command before reboot or shutdown?

Tags: ssh, scp, reboot, systemctl

I want to upload file before reboot or shutdown.
1.From my vps to vps
Setting for upload.service

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/upload.service
[Unit]
Description=upload files into my vps
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target
Requires=network-online.target
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/upload.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Script for upload.sh

```
vim /home/upload.sh
/usr/bin/scp -P 22 -i /home/.ssh/id_rsa /home/wp.bak root@remote_ip:/home
```

It is time to test it.

```
systemctl enable upload
reboot
```

It is verified that wp.bak can uploaded from my vps1 to vps2 at reboot.
2.From pc at home to vps
ssh credential has been established between my pc at home and vps.
Same setting as case1.

```
journalctl -u upload
Started upload files into my vps.
ssh: connect to host xxxxxxxxxx port 22: Network is unreachable
lost connection
```

It is no use to write `After=network.target` as `After=network.target ssh.service`.

Do as nbari say.

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/upload.service
[Unit]
Description=upload files into my vps
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target
After=network.target network-online.target 
Requires=network-online.target network.target    

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/debian9/upload.sh  

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


sudo vim  /home/upload.sh 
/usr/bin/scp -P 22 -i /home/.ssh/id_rsa /home/wp.bak root@remote_ip:/home 

sudo systemctl daemon-reload 
sudo systemctl enable upload
```

Reboot pc.

```
sudo journalctl -u upload
-- Logs begin at Fri 2018-04-27 10:46:34 HKT, end at Fri 2018-04-27 11:00:23 HKT
Apr 27 10:46:51 hwy systemd[1]: Started upload files into my vps.
```

It seems that upload service works fine.

issue1:
Why

```
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/upload.sh
```

works fine on my vps?

Why

```
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/upload.sh
```

can work instead of

```
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/upload.sh
```

in my home pc?

issue2:

wp.bak is a big file more than 3G.
`time /usr/bin/scp -P 22 -i /home/.ssh/id_rsa /home/wp.bak root@remote_ip:/home` cost me 3000s (50 minutes,almost one hour) or more.
Get the file size in my pc

```
ls  -al  /home/wp.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 debian9 debian9 3977379840 Apr 22 12:23 /home/wp.bak
```

Get the uploaded file size in my vps.

```
ssh root@vps_ip
ls  -al  /home/wp.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 63045632 Apr 27 02:46 /home/wp.bak
```

Why only 1.6% ,small part of it uploaded?
63045632/3977379840=0.0158
My servant--home computer lied to me.
Please give a explanation in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was available to upload the file using `scp` before rebooting, using a slightly different configuration for the service using this: `/etc/systemd/system/upload.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=upload files into my vps
Requires=network.target
After=network.target
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/bin/bash /root/upload.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I had to use `RemainAfterExit=true`, instead of `ExecStart=/bin/true`

After creating the service I run `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl enable yourservice`

I tested using this in the `upload.sh`:

```
scp /root/foo.txt foo@10.10.1.14:
```

Previously I setup the ssh-keys to prevent getting prompt for the password/passphrase

The output of `journalctl -u upload`:

```
Apr 26 08:35:53 my-vm systemd[1]: Started upload files into my vps.
Apr 26 08:35:53 my-vm systemd[1]: Starting upload files into my vps...
```

As a fallback you could also use:

```
upload.sh && reboot
```

In this case, it will only reboot if your `upload` script succeed.

Comment: Why changing  `ExecStart=/bin/true` into `RemainAfterExit=true` take effcet ?

Comment: Why can't upload big files?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature regarding `RemainAfterExit` check this answers https://stackoverflow.com/q/38072849/1135424, did you manage to upload at least a file?

Comment: successfully upload a small file(80kb)  into my vps from home pc,why can't big one?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature nice, at least first goal achieved, my guess regarding  "big files" maybe a timeout, give a try using `TimeoutSec=infinity`

Answer (score 2):

So I created a service file like below

```
root@vagrant:/etc/systemd/system# cat shutdownscript.service
[Unit]
Description=...
After=network-online.target network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
#RemainAfterExit=true
#ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "cd /home/vagrant/ && wget https://download-cf.jetbrains.com/webstorm/WebStorm-2017.2.6.dmg"

[Install]
WantedBy=reboot.target
```

Then enabled the same like below

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable shutdownscript
```

And did a reboot. After the reboot

```
$ ls ~/*.dmg
/home/vagrant/WebStorm-2017.2.6.dmg
```

[image: File downloaded on Shutdown]

PS: The reason I chose downloading file instead of `scp` was that I didn't have a external server to `scp` to and I wanted to make sure dns resolution happens. But this should work on `scp` also

Answer (score 2):

```
[Unit]
Description=upload files into my vps
Requires=network.target
After=network.target
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/bin/bash /root/upload.sh
TimeoutSec=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```