# 'nfs-server' state in 'service_facts' differ from 'ansible.builtin.systemd'

Tags: service, ansible, systemd, ansible-facts

Running a CentOS 8 Stream server with `nfs-utils` version 2.3.3-57.el8 and using `ansible-playbook` core version 2.11.12 with a test playbook

```yaml
- hosts: server-1
  tasks:
    - name: Collect status
      service_facts:

      register: services_state
    - name: Print service_facts
      debug:
        var: services_state

    - name: Collect systemd status
      ansible.builtin.systemd:
        name: "nfs-server"
      register: sysd_service_state

    - name: Print systemd state
      debug:
        var: sysd_service_state
```

will render the following results

**service_facts**

```json
...
"nfs-server.service": {
                    "name": "nfs-server.service",
                    "source": "systemd",
                    "state": "stopped",
                    "status": "disabled"
},
...
```

**ansible.builtin.systemd**

```json
...
"name": "nfs-server",
        "status": {
            "ActiveEnterTimestamp": "Tue 2022-10-04 10:03:17 UTC",
            "ActiveEnterTimestampMonotonic": "7550614760",
            "ActiveExitTimestamp": "Tue 2022-10-04 09:05:43 UTC",
            "ActiveExitTimestampMonotonic": "4096596618",
            "ActiveState": "active",
...
```

The NFS Server is very much running/active but the `service_facts` fails to report it as such.

Other services, such as `httpd` reports correct state in `service_facts`.

Have I misunderstood or done something wrong here? Or have I run in to an anomaly?

Comment: Since it could explain your observation, do you have [fact caching enabled](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html#enabling-fact-cache-plugins) in your environment and setup? If so, how it is configured?

Comment: I haven’t done any configuration at all, so I assume it’s set to the default. In a previous run I had the service enabled, which showed in service_facts so it’s not completely “stuck”

Comment: This question was flagged to "Close" with "A community-specific reason" and "Not about programming or software development", but currently and based on the current finding it seems to be about debugging the code of [`ansible/modules/service_facts.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/service_facts.py). So it is about software development then?

Comment: @U880D Then he needs to show the code here. [ask] All I see is systemd related things.

Comment: @Rob The question did start in Ansible, and whether I used the syntax correctly or if there was a problem in Ansible. The fact that my issue would end up being a problem in systemd was unclear to me at the time of posting. At what Stackexchange instance would you have me post it?

Comment: If your question relates to systemd, hover over the tag and read that popup

Answer (score 1):

Running RHEL 7.9, `nfs-utils` 1.3.0-0.68.el7, `ansible` 2.9.27, I was able to observe the same behavior and to reproduce the issue you are observing.

It seems to be caused by "two" redundant service files (or the symlink).

```bash
ll /usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs*
...
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1044 Oct  1  2022 /usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   18 Oct  1  2022 /usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs.service -> nfs-server.service
...

diff /usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs.service /usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; echo $?
0
```

Obviously a status request call to systemd will produce the expected result.

```bash
systemctl status nfs
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/nfs-server.service.d
           └─order-with-mounts.conf
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2022-10-01 22:00:00 CEST; 4 days ago
  Process: 1080 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c if systemctl -q is-active gssproxy; then systemctl reload gssproxy ; fi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1070 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd $RPCNFSDARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1065 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1070 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nfs-server.service

systemctl status nfs-server
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/nfs-server.service.d
           └─order-with-mounts.conf
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2022-10-01 22:00:00 CEST; 4 days ago
  Process: 1080 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c if systemctl -q is-active gssproxy; then systemctl reload gssproxy ; fi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1070 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd $RPCNFSDARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1065 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1070 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nfs-server.service
```

However, a test playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: nfs_server
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Gather Service Facts
    service_facts:

  - name: Show Facts
    debug:
      var: ansible_facts
```

called via

```bash
sshpass -p ${PASSWORD} ansible-playbook --user ${ACCOUNT} --ask-pass service_facts.yml | grep -A4 nfs
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
PLAY [nfs_server] ***************

TASK [Gather Service Facts] *****
ok: [test.example.com]
--
      ...
      nfs-server.service:
        name: nfs-server.service
        source: systemd
        state: stopped
        status: enabled
      ...
      nfs.service:
        name: nfs.service
        source: systemd
        state: active
        status: enabled
```

and report for the first service file found(?), `nfs.service` correct only.

**Workaround**

You could just check for `ansible_facts.nfs.service`, the [alias name](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/managing-system-services-with-systemctl_configuring-basic-system-settings).

```bash
systemctl show nfs-server.service -p Names
Names=nfs-server.service nfs.service
```

---

**Further Investigation**

- Ansible Issue #[73215](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/73215) "*`ansible_facts.service` returns incorrect state*"
- Ansible Issue #[67262](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/67262) "*`service_facts` does not return correct state for services*"

It might be that this is somehow caused by [What does status "`active (exited)`" mean for a systemd service?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241970/) and [`def _list_rh(self, services)`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/service_facts.py#L147) and even if there is already set [`RemainAfterExit=yes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072849/) within the `.service` files.

```bash
systemctl list-units --no-pager --type service --all | grep nfs
  nfs-config.service           loaded    inactive dead    Preprocess NFS configuration
  nfs-idmapd.service           loaded    active   running NFSv4 ID-name mapping service
  nfs-mountd.service           loaded    active   running NFS Mount Daemon
● nfs-secure-server.service    not-found inactive dead    nfs-secure-server.service
  nfs-server.service           loaded    active   exited  NFS server and services
  nfs-utils.service            loaded    inactive dead    NFS server and client services
```

For further tests

```bash
systemctl list-units --no-pager --type service --state=running
# versus
systemctl list-units --no-pager --type service --state=exited
```

one may also read about [NFS server active (exited)](https://superuser.com/questions/1627335/nfs-server-active-exited) and [Service Active but (exited)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387310/).

*... please take note that I haven't done further investigation on the issue yet. Currently also for me it is still not fully clear which part in the code of [`ansible/modules/service_facts.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/service_facts.py) might causing this.*

Comment: Wow, that’s some solid investigation! I did see the issue you linked but I think that case was a race condition resolved with a pause or an “until”. I’ll check that service file on Monday when I’m back at the office.